# Django 3 update value of a ManyToMany field Boolean

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-3.0

I'm creating an exam app, Many Questions to Many Exams.
One of the parameters is 'is_correct', which is a bool.

for some reason, when i save the 'is_correct' on a question, the field changes globally (on the Question model) and become 'True' / 'False' to every one.

How can i update the specific question for the specific exam only?

Current code:

```
exam_data = Exam.objects.get(exam_token=exam_token)
if request.method == 'POST':
    choice = request.POST.get('answer')
    question_id = request.POST.get('question_id')
    correct_answer = exam_data.questions.get(id=question_id).answer
    if choice == correct_answer:
        question = exam_data.questions.get(id=question_id)
        question.is_correct = True # Change to True
        question.save() # After saving here, it changes for the model globally
    else:
        ...same but for False...
```

Model Question:

```
class Question(models.Model):
# Data
topic = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TOPICS)
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

LEVEL = (('EASY', 'EASY'), ('MEDIUM', 'MEDIUM'), ('HARD', 'HARD'))
level = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LEVEL)

# Answers
option1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
option2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
option3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
option4 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
# Right answer
answer = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.title} , {self.topic}, Question answered right: {self.is_correct}'
```

Model Exam:

```
class Exam(models.Model):
topic = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TOPICS)
grade = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
STATUS = (('Pending', 'Pending'), ("Completed", "Completed"))
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Pending', choices=STATUS)
questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
exam_taker = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
exam_token = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
exam_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, editable=False)
exam_due_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.topic} | {self.exam_taker} | {self.exam_token} | {self.grade} | {self.status} {self.questions}'
```

Comment: The model should be just that, a model. It shouldn't hold a "global" value, so I'm confused. Can you post your model please?

Comment: Also, you're hitting the DB twice to look up the question - that code can be optimised a little :) Plus, no need to set false if it's not correct, since I guess the default value is false anyway.

Comment: You have wrong database design is_correct should not be set on Question rather on pivot table between Exam and Question

Comment: Added the models, hope it help.
By globally I ment that after the first save, the 'is_correct' is set True for all the  questions of that type, on all the exams

Comment: You mean when you hit the `save` method it updates all records for `Question` to set `is_correct=True`?  Or that every time you check a question after that it says it's correct regardless?

Comment: If the latter, then it's probably `answer` in your response that is getting defaulted to the correct answer somehow.

Comment: Ill elaborate a bit better- 

I've already create 2 exams.
on 1 of them, everything is wrong.
when doing the second exam, and getting a right answer, is sets the it right also on the first exam.

Meaning the Question.is_correct is changing to True for all the exams, for that specific question.

for example, question 2+2 will be True on all the exams, if i answer it right on one of the exams.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to model your relations properly, so instead of setting is_true on Question model you should have what user answered and is_correct in intermediate/pivot table set as  [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

```
class ExamQuestions(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey('Exam', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answered_value = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    is_correct= models.BooleanField()
```

and set the pivot table in ManyToMany relationship

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    ...
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, through='ExamQuestion')
    ....
```

Comment: Can't implement this, the ExamQuestions want Exam to be first, and the Exam ask for ExamQuestion to be first, not sure what im doing wrong..